# How to avoid Conflict of defined seconds() method and ptime seconds(default) method?

Tags: linux, c++11, boost

Here `unsigned long EVTime::seconds()` method is conflicting with `ptime p(d,seconds(s));`. If I change ptime `seconds(s)` to minutes/hours then it works fine.

If i change that `seconds(s)` to `minutes(s)` or `hours(s)` then only it will work. I am new to C++, anyone please help to resolve this conflict.

*evt.cpp*:

```
unsigned long EVTime::seconds()
{
  ptime t(date(1901,Jan,1),time_duration(0,0,0));
  time_duration td = utcdatetime - t;
  return (unsigned long)td.total_seconds();
}

EVTime::EVTime(unsigned long s)
{
  date d(1901,1,1);
  ptime p(d,seconds(s));
  utcdatetime=p;
}
```

*evt.h*:

```
class EVTime
{
public:
  EVTime(unsigned long s);
  unsigned long seconds();
  ptime utcdatetime;
};
```

*main.cpp*:

```
int main()
{
  EVTime t(222l);
  cout<<"seconds since 1901: "<<t.seconds()<<endl;
}
```

Error code:

```
evtime.cpp: In constructor ‘EVTime::EVTime(long unsigned int)’:
evtime.cpp:35: error: no matching function for call to ‘EVTime::seconds(long 
unsigned int&)’
evtime.cpp:14: note: candidates are: long unsigned int EVTime::seconds()
```

Comment: It looks as though your function `seconds()` takes no parameters, but you send it `s` when you call it: `ptime p(d,seconds(s));` (I presume the *s are for emphasis?)

Comment: Please remove the emphasis asterisks, they disrupt code and don't really contribute anything to the discussion. If you want to emphasize something in your code, just use a comment. Anyway, I think your problem is that you are relying on `using namespace`. This is a mistake. If you need to use `boost::posix_time::seconds`, spell it `boost::posix_time::seconds` every time, or use a namespace alias.

Comment: Thanks, "boost::posix_time::seconds"  this line works for me

Answer (score 0):

Your function `seconds()` takes no parameters, but you send it `s` when you call it: `ptime p(d,seconds(s));`

This causes the error "no matching function for call to `EVTime::seconds(long unsigned int&)`", since you don't have a matching function.

Either call `ptime p(d,seconds());` or change the `seconds` function signature to take the parameter and do something with it.